# Process HTML checkboxes and their values in PHP using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, continuous-integration

I am trying to access values from a database of which checkboxes are checked using PHP CodeIgniter.

Below is the view. Now what should I do in controller and model?

**View**

```
<form method='post' action='master_data.php'>
<?php

foreach ($material_types as $material_type) {
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='material_type[]' value='1' id ='".$material_type->getID()."'>" . $material_type->getMaterialType() . "</input><br />"; 
}

?>
    <input style="float:right" type='submit' name='submitbtn' value='Completed'></input> 
</form>
```

How do I get the list of materials which is a one-to-many relation with material type?

Comment: Do you mean you have material_types (it appears so), and you want to know how to associate the materials?  Are the materials also checkboxes?

Comment: `$material_type->getID()` - something like this belongs to controller.....do you even have access to those methods in your view?

Comment: yes they are also checkboxes and i am able to access materials but all are getting displayed and i want only those materials to be displayed of whose material_type checkboxes are checked and Matteo i have acces to these methods in my view